# React Native's Jest Test Snapshot Visualization

Tags: react-native, jestjs

For complex React Native views it is rather difficult to determine whether screen was rendered correctly using only snapshot's code.
Does anybody know the tool (algorithm) how to visualize React Native's Jest test snapshots and view what was rendered by Jest engine?

Comment: you need to run [E-2-E testing](https://medium.com/@reime005/react-native-end-to-end-testing-d488e010e39f), am I right?

Comment: @skyboyer, Not exactly. When I run jest test like `const tree = renderer.create(
        <View ... />
      )
      .toJSON()
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()` it generates a snapshot and then in next iterations compares it with previously generated etalon. When something changed in a component, it shows the difference. But, it is difficult to see, whether snapshot was generated correctly looking only on snapshot's code (mockup). And I want to find something how to see what was generated, e.g. convert it to image and look at it visually.